# IOS the application view

Tags: iphone, uiview

My question is what is the view at the top of the view hierarchy called?

I am trying to use the passthroughViews property of a popover controller to allow user action with all other views. I want to experiment with this a little, but I'm not sure how to refer to all of those views. I have code like this, but I think that I can replace self.view with something else

```
popOverController.passthroughViews = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.view, popOverController, nil];
```

I am thinking that I can substitute something like [rootview subviews] as an array of all views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view at the top of the view containment hierarchy is the window. You can access it from any view in the window using `[someView window]`. The window is the only view in the hierarchy that doesn't have a superview.

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of that one. One note to those who are interested is that this only works once the view (someView in your example) has been added to the hierarchy. This probably occurs using the addSubview method. But in the case of a popover, addSubview is not used.

Comment: But in the case of a popover, addSubview is not used. With a popover, this doesn't happen until presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections: is called.